# Template class map insert VS Non template map insert

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, std, stdmap

I am trying to understand why the std::map.insert() function is behaving differently.

Example of template class std::map insert function:

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <map>
        #include <limits>

        template<class K, class V>
        class container
        {
        private:
        std::map<K,V> m_map;
        public:
        container(const V Val)
        {
        m_map.insert(m_map.begin(),std::make_pair(std::numeric_limits<K>::lowest(),Val));
        }
        const V operator[](const K key)
        {
        return (--m_map.lower_bound(key))->second;
        }
        };

        int main()
        {
        container<unsigned int, char> c('A');
        std::cout<<std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::lowest()<<":"<<c[std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::lowest()]<<"\n";
        std::cout<<"1:"<<c[1]<<"\n";
        std::cout<<"2:"<<c[2]<<"\n";
        std::cout<<"3:"<<c[3]<<"\n";
        std::cout<<"4:"<<c[4]<<"\n";
        std::cout<<"5:"<<c[5]<<"\n";
        std::cout<<std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()<<":"<<c[std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()]<<"\n";
        return 0;
        }
```

Output:

```
0:A
1:A
2:A
3:A
4:A
5:A
4294967295:A
```

Example of Non-template std::map insert function:

```
            #include <iostream>
            #include <map>
            #include <limits>
            int main()
            {
            std::map<unsigned int, char> m_map;
            m_map.insert(m_map.begin(),std::make_pair(std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::min(),'A'));
            std::cout<<std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::min()<<":"<<m_map[std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::min()]<<"\n";
            std::cout<<"1:"<<m_map[1]<<"\n";
            std::cout<<"2:"<<m_map[2]<<"\n";
            std::cout<<"3:"<<m_map[3]<<"\n";
            std::cout<<"4:"<<m_map[4]<<"\n";
            std::cout<<"5:"<<m_map[5]<<"\n";
            std::cout<<std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()<<":"<<m_map[std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()]<<"\n";
            return 0;
            }
```

Output:

```
0:A
1:
2:
3:
4:
5:
4294967295:
```

The output of the first example shows that all index from 0 -> 4294967295 has been assigned the character 'A'. In the second example, only the index zero(0) has been assigned the character 'A'.

Now my question is why the first example insert function assigned the same value to all keys in range even though I did only one insert and the second example insert function inserted exactly at one location I hinted.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thank you very much for your answer. I believe now I understand. so if I did not misunderstand the std::map.lower_bound(key) documentation, I believe the lower_bound function actually returning the first element that I inserted. Correct? please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: it returns an iterator to an element greater or equal to the key. that next element in a one-element map is always `end()` that you decrement and return back.

Comment: `m_map[1]` inserts default value (`'\0'`) whereas `c[1]` returns `c.m_map.at(0)`.